# Bit Array with Find Max

Tags: hashtable, time-complexity, bitarray

So bit arrays and hash tables don't seem to inherently allow for a find-max type operation, but there are ways around it. I'm wondering if there's a way using the bit array alone without extra variables, pointers, or manipulating the start/end of the array, in some scenarios. For example...

I have integers {1,...,n} and a n-bit bit array. To keep a subset of the integers, I use the integer itself as the key in the bit array and set the bit to 1 if it is in the subset, or 0 if it is not.

For example for integers {1,2,3,4} and subset {1,3), the bit array would look like {1,0,1,0}.

It seems like there's no way to do this without somehow moving the bits around which leads me to believe the O(1) dream is dead and perhaps the bit array won't work. Is something like this possible in O(log n)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finding the highest set bit on a bit array of length n is O(n).  If you need better, then you'll need to choose another data structure, or keep a high-water mark along with your bitmap.